# How to get attributes from a XML file?

Tags: c#, xml

I have .xml  like this:

```
<Type>
  <Connections>
    <Conn ServerName="serv1" DataBase="Persons" User="admin" Pass="123"/>
    <Conn ServerName="serv2" DataBase="Type123" User="admin" Pass="123"/>
  </Connections>
  <UDLFiles>
    <UDL Path="C:\Test.UDL>
  </UDLFiles>
</Type>
```

and I want to save all the ServerNames in `string[] ServerNames;` all the DataBases in `string[] DataBases;` and so on... How to get all these Atributes of this XML?
I try it with:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(path);
        XmlNodeList conn = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Conn");
        foreach (XmlNode item in conn)
        {
            //item.Attributes;
        }
```

but I cant get Atributes with this code... Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cast to [XmlElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.aspx) instead of XmlNode.  Then you can use the Attributes property.